Finding residues of a cot function
I'm trying to find the residues of
$$ f(z) = \frac{\pi \cot(\pi z) }{z-2} $$
at points $z=0$ and $z=2.$
So first we know that the cot function has simple poles at $z=n$, to find the residue we expand $\cot{(\pi z)}$ around this points:
$$ \cot(\pi z) = ... = \frac{1}{\pi ( z - n ) } - \frac{\pi}{3}(z-n) + O(z-3)^3 $$
Now the residue can be determined as follows:
$$ R ( f(z) , n ) =  \lim_{z\to n} \ (z-n) \frac{\pi \cot(\pi z) }{z-2}  = \frac{1}{n-2} $$
But now when I try to find the residue at $z=2$, I rewrite the function using previous expansion
$$ f(z) = \frac{1}{z(z-2)} - \frac{z}{3(z-2)} + O(z)^3  $$
And here is where I get confused about whether this says us something, clearly there is no pure $1/(z-2)$ term! Does that mean that the residue is zero?

we have :$z=2$ order 2 pole
Therfore:
$$\text{Res}(f(z),z=2)=\lim_{z\to 2} \left({(z-2)^2\frac{\pi \cot(\pi z)}{z-2}}\right)'=\lim_{z\to 2} \pi(\cot(\pi z) -\pi(z-2)\csc^2(\pi z))=0 $$
